# Input filter for class d amplifier

Tags: power-supply, filter, switch-mode-power-supply, emi-filtering, class-d

I have built a ~50W class d amplifier powered by a 12V SMPS. My problem is that the output of the SMPS has high frequency noise. I know that the noise is not audible but I would like to remove all of it, so I decided to put an input filter between the SMPS and the amplifier.

To build the input filter I made a search and found these two options:

1) Standard LC filter:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9q1mV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

2) Common mode choke:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGk2bI.png)</sup>

I know that the first is for differential noise and the second is for common mode noise, but I don't know what is the best solution.

What is the best solution? And why?

Can you also tell me what value should the cut-off frequency have? Should it be as low as possible or should it be over the audible range?

Thank you.

Comment: Class d amps produce switching noise even on perfect supplies so, why so you think you need a filter where you say?

Comment: What is the frequency of the SMPS's noise?

Comment: @Andy aka In order to attenuate the noise coming from the power supply. This because that noise is going directly to the speaker.

Comment: @Daniel Tork 67KHz

Comment: Ok.But,why not use a low-pass filter?You can set its cut-off frequency low enough(smaller anyway than 67KHz) in order to get enough attenuation?

Comment: @Daniel Tork Well the two schematics i posted are both low pass filters. The first is for differential noise, the second for common mode noise. My question is: what is the best choice for a class d amplifier?

Comment: I was referring to this:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_circuit

Comment: @Daniel Tork I am not talking about how to filter some voltage signals. I want to remove noise from the power supply output. My smps is capable of 5A. The power dissipated by a resistor is proportional to I², I don't want to use a giant resistor, and I don't want to dissipate energy while filtering. Power signals are filtered with reactive components because they (theoretically) don't dissipate any power.

Comment: What @Andyaka said. The power supply introduces a noise spectrum above the audible range, and the class D amplifier introduces harmonics above the audible range, the latter having way more energy. You use the same lowpass filter to remove both of them from the audio signal, which will dissipate the energy of the undesired frequency components as heat. This is still way more efficient than a class A, AB or B amplifier.

Comment: @Andyaka : the possibility exists of nonlinear interaction (intermodulation) between the PSU noise and the PWM amp's own switching noise, mixing down into the audio band. Careful audio measurements would be needed to find that. However in the absence of evidence for such a problem, I'll agree with your point.

Comment: @Simon Richter I would like to use two different filters for the two kind of noise that you cited. My intention is to use an output LC filter to attenuate the high frequency noise of the PWM modulator and an input filter for the smps noise. For the second purpose would be better a standard LC filter or a common mode filter?

P.S. I want to use reactive components (LC) only so I expect very little (theoretically none) dissipation through heat.

Comment: @BrianDrummond In the case that you talked about would be better a standard differential LC filter or a common mode filter?